# Networking stops after random time. All interfaces remain connected

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

*Check for duplicate queries, none found*

*Xubuntu 17.04 4.10.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP x86_64*

Will have perfect network connectivity, until networking stops. All pings have "Connection reset by peer", all browsing has "DNS Resolver Issues", cannot be pinged from another computer.

`ifconfig` states that the interface has no IP address. `xfce4-indicator-plugin` says interface is up with no IP address. All internet is configured with DHCP via Mikrotik RB941-2nD-TC. Problem is not exhibited by any other devices in house.

Manually re-connecting the Ethernet or WiFi resumes normal operation, until problem repeats.

```
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)

04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 48)
```